# sbteclipse: Managed dependencies not found by eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, sbteclipse

I created an sbt project. Calling sbt compile on the command line works well:

```
$:[...]/Scala-Parser$ sbt compile
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/[...]/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from [...]/Scala-Parser/project
[info] Set current project to MyProject (in build file:[...]/Scala-Parser/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/heinzi/ftanml/Scala-Parser/}default-d86d09...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.2 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 19 Scala sources to [...]/Scala-Parser/target/scala-2.9.2/classes...
[warn] there were 3 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
[warn] one warning found
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed 26.09.2012 11:01:18
```

The external libraries aren't added to a lib_managed directory, but to ~/.ivy2. Nevertheless compiling and using the dependencies in my classes works fine.
Creating an eclipse project also works fine:

```
$:[...]/Scala-Parser$ sbt eclipse
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/[...]/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from [...]/Scala-Parser/project
[info] Set current project to MyProject (in build file:[...]/Scala-Parser/)
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
[info] MyProject
```

But eclipse then can't compile the project, because it's missing a package that should be offered by a managed library (namely scalatest isn't found). Why is this managed dependency not added to eclipse?

Here my project definition files:

- Sources are in src/main/scala respective src/test/scala
- build.sbt

  name := "MyProject"

  version := "0.1"

  scalaVersion := "2.9.2"
- project/plugins.sbt

  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")
- project/build.sbt

  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.8" % "test"

I'm using SBT 0.11.3 and Eclipse Indigo.

**edit:**

The created .classpath from eclipse looks like:

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry output="target/scala-2.9.2/classes" path="src/main/scala" kind="src"></classpathentry>
  <classpathentry output="target/scala-2.9.2/classes" path="src/main/java" kind="src"></classpathentry>
  <classpathentry output="target/scala-2.9.2/test-classes" path="src/test/scala" kind="src"></classpathentry>
  <classpathentry output="target/scala-2.9.2/test-classes" path="src/test/java" kind="src"></classpathentry>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER"></classpathentry>
  <classpathentry path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" kind="con"></classpathentry>
  <classpathentry path="bin" kind="output"></classpathentry>
</classpath>
```

**edit2:**

I now found out that "sbt test" on the console also isn't working. So I think it isn't a problem of sbteclipse, but of how to handle dependencies for test cases. I asked a new question according to this, because my assumptions for asking this question were wrong: [sbt: Add dependency on scalatest library. Where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601452/sbt-add-dependency-on-scalatest-library-where)

Comment: Did `sbt eclipse` create a `.classpath` file in your project directory?  If so, does that file contain an entry for scalatest?

Comment: Yes it created .classpath and no, that file doesn't contain scalatest. I edited the question to contain the .classpath file content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.8" % "test"
```

to build.sbt in the root directory to get recognized as a dependency.