# sbt: Add dependency on scalatest library. Where?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I created a scala project using SBT and wrote some unit test cases using scalatest. But somehow `sbt test` can't find the org.scalatest package.

Here my project definition files:

- Sources are in `src/main/scala respective src/test/scala`
- `build.sbt`:

  ```
  name := "MyProject"

  version := "0.1"

  scalaVersion := "2.9.2"
  ```
- `project/plugins.sbt`:

  ```
  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")
  ```
- `project/build.sbt`:

  ```
  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.8" % "test"
  ```

I'm using SBT 0.11.3.

Compiling the program using `sbt compile` on the console works fine.
Furthermore I found the scalatest jar in `~/.ivy2`, so SBT must have downloaded it.

But when running `sbt test`, it says

```
object scalatest is not a member of package org
[error] import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
...[many errors alike]
```

And running `sbt eclipse` creates a .classpath that doesn't contain the scalatest jar.

Do I have to specify the test dependencies somewhere else? How should I add the scalatest library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place `libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.8" % "test"` into *build.sbt*, not *project/build.sbt*.

Comment: For using versions later than 1.8, do you know what needs to be added to 'resolvers'?

Comment: You can use the ScalaTest [Sonatype OSS repo](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/scalatest) as described [here](http://www.scalatest.org/download#20m4).